# What would be the easiest way to build some image search tool?

Tags: images, search

I have some needs for building some image search tool but am not an experienced search builder, solution like Algolia doesn't seem to be a perfect fit since the data that I have in my hand doesn't come along with quite good meta tags. I googled it a bit but gets quite confused. Isn't there something easy like Algolia that can solve an image search needs without good meta info?

Comment: Do you want a tool, or do you want to code your own? If code, which language and operating system, or should it be browser based?